# Skip the warning message when using pcg

Tags: matlab, warnings

I am using the pcg iterative method to solve the equation `Ax=b` as follows:

```
x = pcg(A,b,tol,maxit);
```

After each calculation, a message is shown in the command window saying either a convergence has been or has not been reached. 
I tried to disable this message, because I print out some other important information regarding my code while running, and those are lost in between the pcg warning messages!

By means of *flag* option I tried to overcome this problem, but I couldn't. I would appreciate if any one has an idea how to disable these messages.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `pcg` does not issue a warning, it outputs "normal" text to the command window using `sprintf`. Disabling all warnings, as suggested by scmg, won't help with that (+ please don't turn off *all* warnings... It is easy to find out which warning it is and disable only that type of warning in such cases).

From looking at the source code of `pcg` (`edit pcg`) or quickly trying it in MATLAB, you will find out that calling `x = pcg(...)` will create this output message, while calling `[x, fl, rr, it, rv] = pcg(...)` will not create that output. The reason for this is probably that if you only use the output `x`, you might be interested in this convergence information, while if you save them in variables, you will probably do some intelligent checks to ensure convergence and thus don't need the values in the console.

**The elegant way**: Call `pcg` and save this diagnostic information into variables

```
[x, fl, rr, it, rv] = pcg(A,b,tol,maxit);
```

and *check the convergence* in MATLAB! Throw a warning or an error otherwise!

**Quick'n'dirty**: If you just assume that everything will work under all conditions, simply ignore these values and just don't save them into variables at all:

```
[x,~,~,~,~] = pcg(A,b,tol,maxit);
```

Comment: I think one still needs to use what @scmg suggested. As far as I understood pcg produces both normal and warning messages. e.g. this is what I get if I use x = pcg(...) without turning off the warnings:  [[Warning: Input tol may not be achievable by PCG
         Try to use a bigger tolerance 
> In pcg at 265
  In _Code_ at 109
  In _Code_ at 99 
pcg stopped at iteration 39 without converging to the desired tolerance 1e-13
because the method stagnated.
The iterate returned (number 39) has relative residual 1.5e-10.]] If  I use what you proposed the part "pcg stopped..." will only disappear.

Comment: If there are other warnings than those you mentioned, then yes you might want to combine both answers. But one hint: don't disable all warnings. Think and check which warnings can regularly appear, think about why these are ok, and then disable only *these* warnings. That way, any unusual warnings are still displayed, which can be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable all warnings by:

```
warning('off','all')
```

Other options for suppressing warnings can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the specific warning, with:

```
warning('off', 'MATLAB:pcg:tooSmallTolerance');
```

Then re-enable it with:

```
warning('on', 'MATLAB:pcg:tooSmallTolerance');
```

**EDIT:** the option below is not good; see comment at the end.

Alternatively, we might want to use a try/catch block. However, try/catch doesn't work with warning: it only works with error. An [undocumented Matlab feature](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/trapping-warnings-efficiently) allows us to turn the warning into an error:

```
warning('error', 'MATLAB:pcg:tooSmallTolerance');  % call this once
```

Now, we can do this:

```
try
    x = pcg(inputs);
catch me
    disp(me); % me is an MException: look inside to see how to use it
end
```

We don't even have to include a "catch" statement at all: just running `try pcg(...) end` will effectively suppress the warning here (not great, but sometimes useful).

**EDIT:** Actually, when we turn the warning into an error, the function pcg does not get a chance to terminate, and hence it does not return its outputs. As a result, `x` is undefined after the try/catch block.